# What does it mean "inputs must be a list"?

Tags: tensorflow

Below codes show me "inputs must be a list". at this.

```
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

When I define placeholder for input `x`. I have already set a shape as `[None,None]`. I think this shape is 2-dimensional array. However, the code continuously requires list type of `x`.

Below, I have attached all of my codes before training. And this codes are inserted into function of class.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float",[None,None])
y = tf.placeholder("float",[None])

lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(self.n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

pred = tf.matmul(outpus[-1], self.weights['out']) + self.biases['out']
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred,y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(cost)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

self.sess = tf.Session()

self.sess.run(init)
```

Additionally, practical inputs will be float of word sequence and float of label formed as `x=[["aaa","aaa","aaa"],["bbb","bbb"]]`, `y=["c1","c2"]`.

At that, the first element array of `x` is labeled with "c1" and the second is "c2". Especially, size of each element array of `x` cannot be deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#rnn), the argument `inputs` of the function `tf.nn.rnn()` is:

> inputs: A length T list of inputs, each a Tensor of shape [batch_size, input_size], or a nested tuple of such elements.

In your code, the argument `inputs` is `x`, a **Tensor** placeholder of shape `[None, None]`. In order for your code to work, `x` must be a **list of T tensors** of shape `[None, input_lenght]`.

The following code generates a list of tensors as `inputs` and therefore the function `tf.nn.rnn` works.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder("float",[None,16])
y = tf.placeholder("float",[None])

lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(256, forget_bias=1.0)

inputs = []
for t in range(10):
        inputs.append(x)

print(len(inputs))

outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

pred = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], self.weights['out']) + self.biases['out']
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred,y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(cost)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

self.sess = tf.Session()

self.sess.run(init)
```

Note how the placeholder `x` has a defined shape of `[None, input_shape]`. It won't work with a shape `[None, None]` because the first dimensions is the batch_size, which can be `None`, but the second dimension is the size of each item in the input sequence, and that value can't be `None`.

Comment: Thank you. And if it is higher distance between min length and max length of training data, how to produce fixed input size in an aspect of algorithm?